# Comparing two definitions of one-way function

Tags: one-way-function

I'm reading Rafael Pass's lecture notes on one-way function and came across two definitions.

- The first one is: A function $f$ is one-way if $f$ can be computed in P.P.T. and there exists no non-uniform P.P.T. $A$ such that

  $\forall x \in \{0,1\}^*, Pr[A(f(x)) \in f^{-1}(f(x))]=1$

However this definition is considered **imperfect** because (for example) under this definition $f(x)=|x|$ would be hard, because "it will take $2^c$ time to write a valid inverse to something such that $f(x) = c$. " (quoted from the note).

- Then it gives the second definition, $\forall$ nuPPT $A$, $\exists \epsilon$ such that $\forall n \in N$

  $Pr[x \leftarrow \{0,1\}^n; y \leftarrow f(x): f(A(1^n, y)) =y] \le \epsilon(n)$

It seems like I can't appreciate the subtlety here and I have two questions:

1. Why does $f(x)=|x|$ take $2^c$ time to write down an inverse.
2. Why $1^n$ is necessary in definition 2.

Can someone shed some light?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thanks for pointing out. I've changed the second definition to another more commonly used form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that $|x|$ in the exercise denotes the length of the bitstring $x$.

If so, the answer is simple: a [polynomial time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Polynomial_time) algorithm needs to complete in a number of steps bounded by a polynomial function of *the length of its input.*

How long is $|x|$, represented as a bitstring?  Well, it takes $k$ bits to represent a number between $2^{k-1}$ and $2^k-1$, so the length of the input $n = |x|$ is about $\log_2 n$ bits.

Thus, in order for $A$ to be a polynomial-time algorithm, $A(|x|)$ must complete in at most $p(\log_2 |x|)$ steps, where $p$ is some polynomial function.  But writing out a string containing $|x|$ bits obviously takes at least $|x| = 2^{\log_2 |x|}$ steps, which is not bounded above by any polynomial function of $\log_2 |x|$.

Essentially, the problem is that the input $|x|$ given to $A$ is "too short" compared to the expected output $x$.  The way we "fix" this issue is simply by giving $A$ an extra input $1^n$ whose length matches the length of the expected output.  That way, by "padding" the input of $A$ to be at least as long as what its output should be, we effectively allow the running time of $A$ to be a polynomial function of the length of both its input *and* its (expected) output, while still adhering to the standard definition of a polynomial-time algorithm.

In programming, we'd call this a hack, or perhaps a kluge.  But it's a convenient kluge, as it saves us from having to redefine "polynomial time" in crypto differently from the way it's usually defined in complexity theory, and so avoids facilitates communication between these two related fields.

Alas, the cost of this notational uniformity is that the extra $1^n$ argument sometimes appears confusing to new students in crypto — especially as some authors, perhaps out of some misplaced sense of professional embarrassment, seem rather reluctant to explain that it is, indeed, essentially just a notational hack to make the standard definition of "polynomial time" fit what we need in crypto.

Comment: Great answer! It makes a lot of sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: I also find the notation of _time_ counter-intuitive. As you said, a polynomial time algorithm needs to complete in a number of steps bounded by $p(n)$ where $n$ is the length of input. But the definition of  _step_  seems quite loose. One bit-wise addition is a step, so is writing one bit down. But they're quite different operations, how can they compare to each other?

Comment: You can pick a specific [model of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation) to implement your algorithm, and measure the precise time that way. But the nice thing about "polynomial time" is that we don't really need to worry about such details, since, for example, a polynomial multiplied by any constant factor (or any other polynomial!) is still a polynomial. (The trade off here is that "polynomial time" is kind of a loose concept; an algorithm that scales as, say, $O(n^{1000})$ is technically polynomial-time, but unlikely to be practical for very large $n$.)